# Twitter like conversation view using RecyclerView and RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement an Activity similar to Twitter's tweet page. When a tweet is a reply to another tweet, if you scroll up, you can see the original tweet being replied to, which is initially hidden above the screen. Here is the code I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/in_reply_to"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/user_image"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/real_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/user_image"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/user_image"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/real_name"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/user_image"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/user_image"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tweet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/user_image"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Unfortunately, in this code only the original tweet shows up and the RecyclerView remains hidden for some reason. Could someone help me out how to position them in such a way that the RecyclerView is hidden above the screen and is visible only if you scroll up?

Comment: I think it would be best if you provided more than just your xml.

Comment: What more do you need? My code just instantiates the RecyclerView and the subsequent TextViews and ImageView.

Comment: I assumed you wanted help with the RecyclerView hiding as well. As to your layout, why not imbed the original tweet in RecyclerView by creating a special ViewHolder for your original tweet and placing it at the bottom of your RecyclerView? You can inverse your LinearLayoutManager if needed.

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to say, but the original tweet needs to be larger in size and have extra information as well such as the reply, favorite button etc.

Comment: I got that, that's why I recommended setting two different viewholders, a normal one for the other tweets and a special extended viewholder just for the original tweet. The layout for the special viewholder can be larger than the other layouts. Like in the picture half way down this blog post under the "Header" section http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/12/recyclerview-grid-with-header.html

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll look into it. Something I noticed, If I put the RecyclerView below the RelativeLayout, everything works fine. Any clue as to why?

Comment: Sorry, I don't, at least not from just the xml, which from a brief look, looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to expand on my comment above with code. You can have multiple ViewHolders in one RecyclerView.Adapter, each can have different layouts (`R.layout.original_tweet` and `R.layout.other_tweets` here). `getItemViewType()` sets which viewholder to show. I didn't test or run the code so there might be a few bugs, but it should give you an idea at least.

```
public class MyAdapter
        extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    private static final int ORIGINAL_TWEET = 0;
    private static final int OTHER_TWEETS = 1;

    private List<String> mTweets;

    public MyAdapter(List<String> tweets) {
        mTweets = tweets;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;
        if (ORIGINAL_TWEET == viewType) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.original_tweet, parent, false);
            return new OriginalTweetViewHolder(view);
        } else {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.other_tweets, parent, false);
            return new OtherTweetsViewHolder(view);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder instanceof OriginalTweetViewHolder) {
            // populate with tweet data
        } else if (holder instanceof OtherTweetsViewHolder) {
            // populate with tweet data
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mTweets.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {


        if (position == mTweets.size() - 1) {
            // At bottom position
            return ORIGINAL_TWEET;
        } else {
            return OTHER_TWEETS;
        }
    }
}

public static class OriginalTweetViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // ViewHolder fields

    public OriginalTweetViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
    }
}

public static class OtherTweetsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // ViewHolder fields

    public OtherTweetsViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
    }
}
```